# Magento Rating and Review - Not Showing Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, product-review

I need help to show `Review` and `Rating` in backend admin navigation panel under catalog similar to link below: http://www.hostknox.com/images/tutorials/magento/ratings-and-reviews/4-zoom.jpg

I have already checked below steps:

`System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced - Mage_Review - Enabled - Mage_Rating - Enabled`

No changes have been made to `app/etc/modules/Mage_Review.xml`

Is there anything else I can do so I can enable the above mentioned ratings?

Answer (score 2):

thankss..bro..

my problem has been solve after read your problem...in my prblem this setting was disable

**System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced - Mage_Review - Enabled - Mage_Rating - Enabled**